# Calling variable in template from view of backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using `text! plug-in` of require.js to load javascript templates of my backbone project.

Here it is :

```
<table id="showcart">
    <tr><td class="cartitemhead">Item to buy</td><td class="cartitemhead" style="text-align: center;">Quantity</td></tr>
       <% _.each(item, function(item) { %>
            <tr><td><table class="verticallist"><tr><td rowspan="4" style="width: 120px;"><img src="<%=item.PictureName%>" alt="Product" width="95px"/></td><td style="font-weight: bold;"><%=trimString(item.Name,50)%></td></tr><tr><td><i>Available in Stock(s)!</i></td></tr><tr><td><i>Rating: 650Va-390w Input:   Single</i></td></tr></table></td><td class="centertxt"><%=item.QuantityInCart%></td></tr>
       <% }); %>
</table>
```

`item` variable was declared in my view.

```
var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        var item = deserializeJSONToObj(window.localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
        var cartList = _.template(showCartTemplate, {})
        $("#cartlist").html(cartList);
    }
});
```

Model :

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){
   var Cart = Backbone.Model.extend({

   });
});
```

I got one error from console : `Uncaught ReferenceError: item is not defined`.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to indicate somehow the value you want to pass for backbone template. Because you have defined a variable, Underscore template is looking for a value to get replaced with.

For this reason try to pass the model value as an argument to the appended view.

```
var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        var item = deserializeJSONToObj(window.localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
        var cartList = _.template(showCartTemplate, {})
        $("#cartlist").append({item : cartList});
    }
});
```

This way, each time when undercore find a variable `item` it will replace with the value passed as argument to the view.

Comment: Oop! as you said above, pass a model value? actually now my model is empty. What should I keep in my model? (sorry I'm very new with backbone).

Comment: Did you passed the model or collection to the backbone view? I mean you have to point to the backbone model or collection in order to use the model's data.

Comment: I added the model, I pointed the model to view ready, but I really have know idea, what data should I write in my model :|

Comment: If you don't know then how should i know? :) Really a model is a set of object with key value pairs in it. Backbone official site will give you all the needed explanation: http://backbonejs.org/#Model. Maybe if you explain a little bit more what do you want to achieve would be of more help.

Comment: The object `item` was stored in localStorage with key and value like this `var item = {DepartmentID :333,CategoryID:117,ID:711 };` so I should store this object in my model?

Comment: You instantiate the view and pass the model as argument like this: `var view = new CartListView({model: item});`

Comment: @SimoEndre : Instantiated in my router already, but the error still appeared.

Comment: However, `item` is stored in localStorage not a model.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the item key in the object that you pass in _.template

```
var CartListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    render: function(){
        var item = deserializeJSONToObj(window.localStorage.getItem("Cart"));
        var cartList = _.template(showCartTemplate, {item : item})
        $("#cartlist").append({item : cartList});
    }
});
```

Because you can not access the item variable directly in template.